# Hotel booking plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have developed a website for resort in wordpress and it includes room booking system. I want to know which is the free good plugin that can be used for booking rooms.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the following Plugin's :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/motopress-hotel-booking-lite/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/booking/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/sagenda/

almost best Free Booking Plugin's